# How to make javascript code to be embed into html button?

Tags: javascript

I am a noob for learning javascripts

Here I have a javascripts code

I made a button named "click"

when you click the button

it will send a value xx=1 to x

if the value is match with the condition

then it will print "Y", otherwise it will be "N"

but it always cannot shows the messagebox.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script language="javascript">
    function jclass(xx)
    {
       var x=xx;
       if x==1
          alert("Y");
       else
          alert("N");                 
    }
  </script>
  </head> 
  <head>
    <h1><a href="javascript:jclass(1);">click</h1>
  </head>
</html>
```

I have also tried other ways like this.

but it still cannot work.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script language="javascript">
    function jclass()
    {
       var x=1;
       if x==1
          alert("Y");
       else
          alert("N");                 
    }
  </script>
  </head> 
  <head>
    <h1><a href="javascript:jclass();">click</h1>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in `if` condition. The basic [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) syntax requires condition inside parenthesis after `if`.

```js
function jclass(xx){
   var x=xx;
   if (x==1)
      alert("Y");
   else
      alert("N");                 
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="javascript:jclass(1);">click</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the brackets
if(x == 1)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets for comparison,its not python:)
You can check these type of errors in console and act upon exact statement
You should also put curly braces even for a single line in a block or condition to avoid any legacy or formatting issues when running code

Happy Programming

```html
 <html>
        <head><title>test</title>
        <script language="javascript">
        function jclass(xx)
        {
           var x=xx;
           if (x==1) {
              alert("Y");
              }
           else {
              alert("N");                 
              }
        }
      </script>
      </head> 
      <head>
        <h1><a href="javascript:jclass(1);">click</h1>
      </head>
    </html>
```